# How to dump IP packet buffer for wireshark/How to do hexdump in C++?

Tags: c++, networking, ip, wireshark

I have a simple `uint8_t*` IP packet buffer like

```
45 0 0 34 0 0 40 0 40 6 6B 53 C0 A8 FF 6 AC D9 1C EE 0 4D 0 50 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80 2 FD E8 A5 20 0 0 2 4 5 B4 3 3 0 4 2 0 0 0
```

I want to use Wireshark to view it. I saw that I can import an hex dump on Wireshark, but how can I save this buffer as a hex dump for wireshark to open?

Is it possible to concatenate lots of IP packets together?

Comment: use 'freopen', 'printf' functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the data to match the format expected by [`text2pcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html), you can use that tool to convert the data into a pcap (or pcapng) file.  For example:

Here's the data you provided in a format acceptable to `text2pcap`:

```
0000  45 00 00 34 00 00 40 00 40 06 6B 53 C0 A8 FF 06
0010  AC D9 1C EE 00 4D 00 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0020  80 02 FD E8 A5 20 00 00 02 04 05 B4 03 03 00 04
0030  02 00 00 00
0034
```

Since this appears to start with an IPv4 header, you can generate a pcap file with a link layer header type set to `LINKTYPE_RAW`, the value of which is obtained from https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html, as referenced in the `text2pcap` man page.  Alternatively, you can choose to add a dummy Ethernet header to the data, in which case you can omit the link layer header type option as `LINKTYPE_ETHERNET` is the default value; however you do need to add the option to add the dummy Ethernet header.  Here I demonstrate both methods:

**Method 1: Raw IP**

```
text2pcap -l 101 file.hex file.pcap
```

**Method 2: Add dummy Ethernet header**

```
text2pcap -e 0x0800 file.hex file.pcap
```

The `text2pcap` tool is capable of processing any arbitrary number of packets from a file, but note the required format from the man page, i.e. *"Note the last byte must either be followed by the expected next offset value as in the example above or a space or a line-end character(s)."*

By the way, Wireshark itself is also capable of converting the hex data into a pcap file as well using the *File -> Import from Hex Dump...* feature, although Wireshark will always import the hex data as a pcapng file.  You can choose to save the file as pcap though, but there'll always be that intermediate pcapng file generated.  Wireshark should just provide a checkbox to allow the user to select which format to use, just like `text2pcap` does.  I have filed Wireshark [Bug 16724](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16724) to address this.